AWS Lambda runtime error with gogole chromedriver selenium deployed on ECR
I am trying to create a automated process of accepting snapchat invatation to organization. The way it works is we have an email and we get invites to different organizations. Then I use AWS lambda to fetch the email from Workmail and extract the invatation link. This part works fine.
The next part is simulating the accepting the invite. Because snapchat have captcha I can't login into snapchat but what I figured is I can perhaps use google chrome profile session which is already logged in into snapchat. So I use Docker to dockerize my code and all of the directories I need, my Docker file looks like this:
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.12

# Install chrome dependencies and 7-Zip
RUN dnf install -y atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib \
    libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver \
    libXtst pango at-spi2-atk libXt xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
    xorg-x11-xauth dbus-glib dbus-glib-devel nss mesa-libgbm jq unzip

RUN dnf install -y p7zip p7zip-plugins

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR ./

# Copy and run the chrome installer script
COPY ./chrome-installer.sh ./chrome-installer.sh
RUN chmod +x ./chrome-installer.sh
RUN ./chrome-installer.sh
RUN rm ./chrome-installer.sh

# Install selenium
RUN pip install selenium

# Install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install

RUN mkdir -p .config/google-chrome
RUN mkdir -p cookie_temp

# ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
# ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

# Set environment variables from build arguments
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1

# Download the zip file from S3 using AWS CLI
RUN aws s3 cp s3://bucket/google_chromium/Profile1.7z ./.config/google-chrome/Profile1.7z

# Unzip the file
RUN 7z x ./.config/google-chrome/Profile1.7z -o./.config/google-chrome/

RUN chown -R root:root .config/google-chrome

RUN chmod -R 755 .config/google-chrome
RUN chmod -R 755 cookie_temp

RUN chmod o+rx .config/google-chrome
RUN chmod o+rx cookie_temp

# Clean up
RUN rm ./.config/google-chrome/Profile1.7z


COPY cookie_temp/cookies.pkl cookie_temp/
# Copy the main application code
COPY lambda_function.py ./
COPY ssm.py ./
COPY headless_browser.py ./
RUN ls -l ./
# Command to run the Lambda function
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]

So I download a zipped folder that contains Profile 1 which has all cookies and sessions. Then I unzip it and I am trying to access the content of it. But this is were I have an issue
Instead of webdriver being initiated, it always gets an error, in other words I can't start the webdriver. Here is my script code:
class HeadlessBrowser():
    def __init__(self, user_creds, invatation_url):
        # Add a short delay to ensure Chrome processes are terminated
        time.sleep(4)
        print('KILLED')
        #Clean up the profile directory
        profile_path = ".config/google-chrome"
        
        #Set up headless browser options
        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
        #profile_path = "C:/root/.config/google-chrome"
        

        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_path}")
        #chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-pipe")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--log-path=/tmp")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        chrome_options.binary_location = "/opt/chrome/chrome-linux64/chrome"

        service = Service(
            executable_path="/opt/chrome-driver/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver",
            service_log_path="/tmp/chromedriver.log"
        )

        
        self.user_creds = user_creds
        self.invatation_url = invatation_url

        print('REACHED HERE2')
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=service,
        options=chrome_options
        )

Locally it works perfectly fine, but when I deploy and run it from AWS it doesn't..any idea what can I do differently to resolve this?

dont you get any error? try add this one also for AWS run >> chrome_options.add_argument("--single-process")

Thank you for answering. I will try with that argument. By the way the error am getting is just this: from unknown error: failed to write prefs file
So I am not sure what could be the issue, I tried googling it but nothing really comes out of it.

also test with some basic script if you can write on /tmp . Write a file and read it

So I still can't initiate a webdriver..I tried using mkdir in my --user-data-dir but still the same issue.
How do I write it on /tmp?

as any file -> with open("/tmp/foo.txt", "w+") as f: f.write("a") and read it

Ok so it works if I use this:  chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={mkdtemp()}")
But the issue is I would like to use my custom chrome profile which I have in my .config directory so like this:
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome/")
And this is were I get error, the webdriver is not initiating. The folder is indeed there so I know its been accessed.

I found this in my custom library that work selenium on normal server and AWS server, test it but not sure if this will solve: options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/your/path") and this options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'profile': {'exited_cleanly': 'true', 'exit_type': 'none'}})
